# Having problems with the 'distance=' command in Minecraft 1.13.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm having some problems, a problem that seems simple, but seems to keep eluding me.

The command I'm using as a test is this:

```
/gamemode adventure @a[gamemode=creative,distance=..2]
```

Above that, I have this:

```
/gamemode creative @a[gamemode=adventure,distance=3..5]
```

However, when I tried to make another 'boundary' of the same kind with the same commands in the same way, it didn't work, and I have no idea why. The second one does nothing at all, the first one is fine but every time I try make a second or even a third one it does nothing.

Both setups are completely identical in every way, even in other worlds its the same, one works but the other does nothing at all.

The first block is set to Repeat, Unconditional, Always Active, while the one above that it is set to Chain, Unconditional, Always Active, they are about 8 blocks away from each other and I have them the same, even the blocks around their 'borders'

I'm not using any mods. I haven't touched any files since download (other than to add resource packs or maps).

If anyone can explain this and help me out, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Chain command blocks will only run if:

a) it's touching a command block that is pointing towards it, and
b) the command block that it's touching runs at least once.

If either of those are false, then the chain command block will not run. Even if they are one block away, the repeat block will run, but the chain will not because the repeat command block is not touching it.
If they are not touching, then the command block that is a chain command block needs to be a repeat block itself or touching the repeat block while the repeat block is pointing towards it.

Hope this helps!